Windows installer can't recognise my drive with Linux Mint installed on it
After making a Windows 10 bootable drive, I soon realised that the Windows installer could not find identify the main drive within my laptop to install Windows on. I assume this is due to the nature of the drive not being in the NTFS format.
How would I go about formatting the entire drive to the NTFS format while having my Linux Mint installed on it.
enter image description here

"How would I go about formatting the entire drive to the NTFS format while having my Linux Mint installed on it." - You wouldn't; You need to identify the file system you used for Linux and install a third-party driver to support that file system.  Linux to my knowledge CANNOT be installed to NTFS partition, it supports and read NTFS, but only to store data on. You might consider a VM or WSL if you need access to Linux application and their data while within Windows instead of a dual booting linux and Windows. Why did you tag this question with a Windows 7 tag?

I removed the false tag, thanks for the help.

And the Windows installer not "recognizing" (this needs clarification) has nothing to do with the file system of the partitions already there but often a mismatch between its requirements for different modes (GPT for UEFImode; MBR for Legacy/CSM"BIOS" mode). That means if you boot the installer in one mode but the drive is partitioned for the other it'll NOT let you select that drive for installation nor manage it by deleting partitions.

You need to check that then [edit] the question with a screenshot of Disks or Gparted showing the drive layout and then explain what exactly you want to do, replace Mint, dual-boot or what?

I want to completely replace Mint with Windows. I am in the process of making a bootable Windows 10 USB stick with Ventoy at the moment.

Good. I suggest, before anything else, to open UEFI ("BIOS") settings and disable Legacy/CSM support as this assures you'll be booting in UEFI mode. The drive is GPT already so fine for Windows in UEFI mode (probably before you were booting it in Legacy mode). The Windows installer should now see the drive and allow installation provided you delete all partitions (you can keep the ESP, of course, but there's no point, the installer will recreate it anyway and keeping the old one will also keep the Mint bootloader).

From now on adjust your browsing habits and double-check what you install. Doing the wrong thing in Windows has consequences, unlike what happens with most Linux based OSes.

Also keep in mind Windows 10 has less than a years of support left. Make sure you can upgrade to Windows 11 in due time or, better, install it now.

Remove all partitions, then, and install Windows from ISO, letting it repartition the drive. Do not format the whole drive NTFS, since the EFI partition would be FAT32. That said, has Windows 10 ever been installed? If not, you'll need to get a license.

I can't seem to the option for legacy/csm support in my UEFI.

Brand/model?...

ASUS-TUF-FX507Z

Do you think there would be a difference If I tried switching between RAID and AHCI?

Better use AHCI unless you have a reason to use RAID but even in that case better to use soft RAID solutions instead. And it's definitely UEFI so there shouldn't be any problem installing Windows but, again, prefer Windows 11. If when booting external media you see 2 options make sure you choose the one mentioning UEFI.

Okay I have everything working except for the required VMD drivers now. The only problem is that they are in an .exe file only now. I can't install it on linux...

Everything you need to install is included in the Windows installer.
